# automatically execute commands on anaconda prompt startup

Tags: windows, bash, anaconda

In linux I can put commands in my .bashrc file that will automatically execute every time I open terminal. For example, I I have this line in my bashrc

```
conda info --envs
```

I get a list of all the environments. How can I set up my windows installation of anaconda 3 to do the same?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out and am posting the working result in case anyone asks the same question.
Open the anaconda directory and in there open the scripts directory. Open the file 'activate.bat' in a text editor. add any commands you want to execute after 'line 26 :END'
with the prefix '@CALL' So for example my line 27 read '@CALL conda info --envs'. Now every time I open an anaconda prompt, that command executes.

Comment: I was able to use this bat file to extend my PATH so I can use neovim. I don't have admin privs so this will allow for me to run
`@CALL set PATH=C:\path\to\neovim:%PATH%`
works like a charm!